# OLE DB was unable to convert a value to the data type requested

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssas, cube

The below happens on SQL Server Edition  (2017 Standard), SSAS version is 14.0.6.443

The problem is summarized best by the error messages during processing:

> Errors in the back-end database access module. OLE DB was unable to convert a value to the data type requested for column 'dbo_Fact_Purchase_Order_Detail0_2'.
>
> Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while processing the 'Fact Purchase Order Detail' partition of the 'Supplier Transactions' measure group for the 'Cube_Name' cube from the SSAS PRD database.

At first the erro seemed to be related to the datatypes. Other SSAS instances on different servers can read the data, the SSAS instance in question cannot. The issue seems to be in SSAS or the OLE DB connector (from SSAS).

## **The situation**

We are busy installing a new development and production sql server. The ETL (using SSIS) works already and we came down to processing the cube, what doesn't go that well.

In Visual Studio we can deploy the same SSAS cube project to the new and old servers. The old servers is able to process the cube, but the new ones are unable to process the cube.
The underlying data source view only differs by the server name

After googling and testing we think / thought the issue is related to a collation or language setting: because we found the following possible useful hits on google:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/55f98b80-70e9-4b77-a0fd-3e1a5f429104/regional-settings/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/languages-and-collations-analysis-services?view=sql-server-2017/
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8e0e761c-1c53-48bf-ba21-b4849e31221d/errors-in-the-backend-database-access-module-ole-db-was-unable-to-convert-a-value-to-the-data-type?forum=sqlanalysisservices/
- http://nisalbi.blogspot.com/2017/08/how-to-uninstall-sql-server-analysis.html

We have tried the following:

- Execute the query generated for cube processing on the source db: **Success**
- Deploy and process the SSAS project to the old production and development
  server: **Success**
- Excluded the 0.000000 value with a customized query in the partion properties of a measure group. **Successful processing**
- Compare the settings of the old and new servers and SSAS databases are the same. **They are the same**
- Process only the dimension was **success**
- Change user who runs the SSAS service agent to my personal account, **no success in processing**
- Compare all settings argued by the above posted doc.microsoft.com link **No differences**
- Back-up and restore the live cube on the old production server to the new production server and process the cube **processing wasn't a success**
- Refresh the datasource view **did not help**
- Check Table and Database on invalid values **All values are valid**
- Changed the 0.000000 to a `NULL` value **Did not help**
- Added `Packet Size=32767` to the connection string of the data source, **no success**
- We have also tried the *Native OLE DB \ SQL Server Native Client 11.0* instead of the *Native OLE DB\Microsoft OLE DB Provider* for SQL Server, did not gave any positive result.
- Converted values from `Decimal` to `Float`. `Float` and `Double`, used in SSAS, are identical, but still processing **Failed** on the same error.
- Uninstalled SSAS en made a new installation, same error, **no succes** http://nisalbi.blogspot.com/2017/08/how-to-uninstall-sql-server-analysis.html
- Deleted the dimension where the issue pointed to, success, it can also be that two apparently correspondent columns have different data definitions. Replace them from the. correct this, add them to the datasource view again and it should work. Worked on a different server

We expected that the cube should process successfully since we have the same database structure as data source view and we could not found any differentiation in the general and connection properties between the old and new servers.

Comment: The error message tells you converting *a* column failed; how have you determined the column in question is the one with the `0.000000` value and not another column of the same row, or indeed a different row also excluded? Hook up Profiler and see what query SSAS issues to fetch the data to determine what column `dbo_Fact_Purchase_Order_Detail0_2` actually corresponds to , and if there are any interesting discrepancies between it and the actual types. Also (bit of a long shot, but still) try `DBCC CHECKTABLE(table) WITH (DATA_PURITY)` to see if there's any integrity problems.

Comment: Oh, and check the cube in SSAS to see what the OLE DB type of the column is. The *target* type may be `Double`, but that's just what SSAS uses internally. To read the column in the first place, it'll use an OLE DB call where the type should match the DB type (`DBTYPE_NUMERIC`); check the fact column type.

Comment: Yes, that's clear, but since you haven't included the query I've assumed this is something of the form `SELECT a, b, c, d, e .. FROM t WHERE d <> 0.000000`. It excludes a row from processing, but it is not clear that the value in `d`, and only that, is the cause of the problem. What is the query SSAS fires, and what does it use as the expression/column for `dbo_Fact_Purchase_Order_Detail0_2`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert we know it is in the 0.000000 value, because when we exclude these values the cube processes fine. We tested this as mentioned in bullet three.
Other measure groups have the same issue, so it is not bound to one measure group but project wide. 
```CHECKTABLE``` and ```CHECKDB``` ```WITH DATA_PURITY``` confirmed no invalid values are used in the specific source table and source database in general.

Comment: @JeroenMostert how do I check the DB type the OLE DB uses? (First time installing a server and belonging sql services)

Comment: Never mind, I got confused with SSIS on that one. SSAS doesn't include any typed view of the underlying data, only the internal type(s) (stored as XML schema types). Obviously it will do some conversion at one point when consuming the results of the queries it generates, but that's not exposed.

Comment: Just for completeness, have you installed the latest version (Cumulative Update 14 as of writing), in case this is an SSAS bug that's already been squashed?

Comment: The query shows you that the column SSAS has a problem with is `AmountUnitVolume (PDITVL)`; double-check that that's the one you were expecting.

Comment: If you mean deployment server being 14.0, yes we have the cumulative update 14

Comment: [Cumulative Update 14](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4484710/cumulative-update-14-for-sql-server-2017) means your SSAS version is 14.0.2.451 (SSMS apparently shows this as 14.0.245.1); it's a coincidence that the major version of 2017 is also 14.

Comment: The SSAS version is 14.0.6.443

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193698/discussion-between-bobstar-and-jeroen-mostert).

Comment: Hello I face the same problem and I can't find a solution on this post
Could you please add your solution in the comment or in answer ?
I tried to convert all my decimal columns to float and it works for some dimensions.